# How to do updates to TeX Live under WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, latex, texlive

I want to use latex inside WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 is what shows in my Apps and Features) because I want a linux-based install (to use bash scripts, etc.). I managed to install TeX Live following instructions for [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I have a `/usr/local/texlive/2018` that is OK, and the latex commands, etc. work fine.

The trouble I have is with updates or installing other packages. `tlmgr` seems partially borked in WSL. For example, I want to install packages and fonts:

```
$ sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

I get an error about `Cannot find main repository, you have to tag one as main!` (but there are also errors about missing `xzdec`).

So, I try to set the repository, and still get the `xzdec` error:

```
$ sudo tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
tlmgr: Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: Continuing anyway ...
tlmgr: setting default package repository to http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

Googling the `xzdec` package error, I [found it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install xzdec`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180230/kubuntu-texlive-manually-installed-tlmgr-not-working). But on my WSL I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xzdec
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xzdec
```

Can `xzdec` be installed in WSL? What's the trick? More info about [xzdec](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xzdec&searchon=names)

Is TeX Live the best option for LaTeX under WSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating my Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

It installed a bunch of stuff (I apparently have never done that since installing WSL from the Microsoft Store).

Afterwards, the `$ sudo apt-get install xzdec` succeeds, and so do the `$ sudo tlmgr ...` commands.

However, I'm now realizing there's a conflict with the default Ubuntu 18.04 installs of latex. Before you install TeX Live (2018), make sure you [remove the default install first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446616/17868).